# Python : How to import a module if I have its path as a string?

Tags: python, import

Lets say I have path to a module in a string module_to_be_imported = 'a.b.module'
How can I import it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> m = __import__('xml.sax')
>>> m.__name__
'xml'
>>> m = __import__('xml.sax', fromlist=[''])
>>> m.__name__
'xml.sax'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the build-in `__import__` function. For example:

```
import sys

myconfigfile = sys.argv[1]

try:
    config = __import__(myconfigfile)
    for i in config.__dict__:
        print i            
except ImportError:
    print "Unable to import configuration file %s" % (myconfigfile,)
```

For more information, see:

- [Python Documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html)
- [Python.org - [Python Wpg] Import a module using a string](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/winnipeg/2007-December/000322.html)

Comment: Use `fromlist` parameter otherwise you get `a` instead of `a.b.module` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102252/python-how-to-import-a-module-if-i-have-its-path-as-a-string/3102318#3102318

Answer (score 0):

```
x = __import__('a.b.module', fromlist=[''])
```

[Reference](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm)

Comment: >>> n =__import__('mobius.api')
>>> n
<module 'mobius' from '/home/rhiwale/Desktop/nfsrepo/rohit/mobius/../mobius/__init__.pyc'>
>>> 
>>> for i in n.__dict__:
...   print i
... 
settings
__builtins__
docs
__file__
polls
__package__
__path__
api
video
__name__
__doc__
ccb
>>> 

Why mobius gets imported instead of mobius.api ?

Comment: See comment below for answer. Updating my answer now.